# SQL Server : request with LEFT OUTER JOIN condition on several tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join

I'd like to get a result containing the information about the controls performed on several products, all the measurements contained in these controls and, if they exist, the limits of the product controlled by the control.

Ideally, the request I'd like to make would be like this :

```
SELECT c.ControlDate,
       m.Value,
       l.Upperlimit
FROM control c, measurement m
LEFT OUTER JOIN
LIMIT l
    ON l.ProductRef = c.ProductRef AND
       l.Spec = c.Spec AND
       l.CharacRef = m.CharacRef AND
       l.Active = 1
WHERE m.ControlRef = c.ControlRef 
...and many conditions concerning the m and the c tables
```

I know I can't do this :-)
But I can't find an effective solution to get the results.

I tried with a temporary table (containing all the  but I don't find the solution to make it effective.
Do you have a suggestion about the way I should do this?

Comment: You _can_ do this, in the sense that your query seems valid other than several things being out of order.  But as @Gordon mentioned, you should do away with those commas in the `FROM` clause and join using the `ON` clause instead.

Comment: You are doing select from c join (m left join l) here. Is that what you want?

Comment: It states `SQL Server`, but the `LIMIT 1` keyword is not available there.

Comment: @NickyvV, looks like table name `LIMIT` with alias `l`. (Bad choice of name...)

Comment: @jarlh Oh wow.. I missed that :)

Comment: @All : thanks for your comments! I implemented the solution given by Gordon and it works great.

Answer (score 1):

Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax, with the conditions in the `ON` clause.

I would start with:

```
select c.ControlDate, m.Value, l.Upperlimit
from control c left join
     measurement m
     on m.ControlRef = c.ControlRef left join
     limit l
     on l.ProductRef = c.ProductRef and
        l.Spec = c.Spec and
        l.CharacRef = m.CharacRef and
        l.Active = 1
where ...and many conditions concerning the m and the c tables
```

If you want all control dates, then the conditions on the `c` tables should also go in the (appropriate) `on` clause.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works like a charm. I'll avoid commas from now on!